# How to get data into React when doing server-side rendering?

Tags: express, reactjs

I have a web app where users can log in.
After users log in, they are authenticated by using Express and [Passport](http://passportjs.org/).

The code after successfully authenticating users is as the following.

```
router.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("index", { user: req.user });
});
```

Now, user's data is stored in `user`, so if I want to render user's email on the index page, I can do it by `user.email`. There is no problem so far.

---

I use React.js as my choice of Javascript library, and the problem arises here.

Let's say that I want to show user's email through React.js on the index page after they logged in, so my code ended up like the following.

```
var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <p>
        Your current email is {this.props.email}.
      </p>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<HelloMessage email={user.email} />, document.getElementById('hello'));
```

My intention here is that I can retrieve user's email the same way I retrieve on index page without React.js. So, I put `user.email` as my prop for email, but this clearly didn't work. It ended up returning error message saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: user is not defined`. Does anyone know how to retrieve data for the email using React.js?

Comment: error at which line?

Comment: It is not completely clear, but my guess is the last line, specifically "email={user.email}".